# How to protect SELECT * FROM var1 WHERE var2 statements from SQLInjection

Tags: python, sql, django, sql-injection, django-2.2

I am making a website in django where I want the user to put in a table id and group id and then return the table and group that the put in. However, I have only found statements that are prone to SQL injection. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```py
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
qry = "SELECT * from %s WHERE group_id = %i;" % (assembly_name, group_id)

mycursor.execute(qry)

return mycursor.fetchall()
```

Or do something that achieves the same thing?

I have tried doing something like this:

```py
assembly_id = 'peptides_proteins_000005'
group_id = 5

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE group_id = %s", [assembly_id, group_id])

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

but I get this error:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''peptides_proteins_000005' WHERE group_id = 5' at line 1
```

Comment: you could try to use the Django ORM, its protected against these kind of security risks.

Comment: You add the arguments as a list or tuple as the second argument to the `execute` call instead of using `%` formatting.

Comment: The second argument to `cursor.execute` is for parameters, as seen in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Comment: @KlausD. That does not work when you have a variable in the table spot

Comment: @CraigMeier  See above

Comment: As Ivan mentioned, you should use the ORM. Put the model names in a dictionary for example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman My database is too big to put put in models. It would take around a day of loading for all the tables to be in the models, and I only need to do 1 or 2 queries on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically not possible to bind table names. For SELECT statements, the easiest way is to sanitize table name candidates by whitelisting.

Check whether the overhead of using abstraction or some way of constraining user input to the finite set of valid names as part of the user interface may be justified.

Comment: I am new to sql and django could you give an example of how to do this?